# Active nav link is not shown at the correct section because of header offset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, anchor

In this below example I have got two issues.

**1 -** Active nav link is not shown at the correct section when clicked on a nav link because of header offset calculation, I think it assumes it is not reached to the designated section, you have to scroll header height more manually than active link background color highlights.

**2 -** During scrolling highlight passes by each link and creates unpleasant effects for example when you are in the Amenities section and click on Contact to reach to contact section.

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });

  navLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active-link");
    if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
      li.classList.add("active-link");
    }
  });
});

/*Menu Toggle*/
$(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass("nav--open", 500);
  $(".overlay").toggleClass("showOverlay");
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});

$(".overlay").click(function() {
  $(".menu-toggle").removeClass("open");
  $(".nav").toggleClass("nav--open");
  $(".overlay").removeClass("showOverlay");
});

$(".nav a").on("click", function() {
  $(".menu-toggle").removeClass("open");
  $(".nav").toggleClass("nav--open");
  $(".overlay").removeClass("showOverlay");
});

/*Smooth Scrolling*/
// Get the height of the header for offsetting
var headerHeight = $(".header-container").height();

// Attach the click event
$('.nav-link').bind("click", function(e) {

  var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
  var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - headerHeight;

  $('html').animate({
    'scrollTop': scrollToPosition
  }, 900, function(target) {
    window.location.hash = target;
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
<!--Back To Top Script-->
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = document.querySelector('.scrollTop');
  scroll.classList.toggle("active", window.scrollY > 500)
})

function scrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*My Special Menu*/

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header-container {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7abff6 0%, #03a9f4 100%);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  /*width: 95%;
     max-width: 1000px;
    */
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: 84.4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo__text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 18px;
}

.logo__text span {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.logo__text1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 220px;
}

.logo__text1 h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
}


/*a.nav-link.availability-button {
            color: #ffffff !important;
            border-width: 0px !important;
            letter-spacing: 1.5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 700 !important;
            background-color: #edbb5f;
            padding-top: 10px !important;
            padding-right: 18px !important;
            padding-bottom: 10px !important;
            padding-left: 18px !important;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        a.nav-link.availability-button:hover {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
            transform: translateY(-5px);
            background-color: #edbb5f;
            padding-top: 10px !important;
            padding-right: 18px !important;
            padding-bottom: 10px !important;
            padding-left: 18px !important;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }*/

.nav a.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
  clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
  transition: -webkit-clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
  transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
  transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms, -webkit-clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
}

.nav--open {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(250% at top right);
  clip-path: circle(250% at top right);
}

.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
  border-left: 1px solid #575766;
  border-right: 1px solid #575766;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
  /*.nav li:last-child {
                display: none;
            }*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .check-button {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.nav-link {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  outline: none;
}


/*.nav-link:hover,
        .nav-link:focus {
            background: #74d057;
            color: #fff;
        }*/

.nav--icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  text-align: right;
  /*color: #000;*/
}

i.fas.fa-home.nav--icon {
  color: #552401;
}

i.far.fa-image.nav--icon {
  color: #9a57d8;
}

i.fas.fa-bed.nav--icon {
  color: #ef991f;
}

i.far.fa-thumbs-up.nav--icon {
  color: #5912d0;
}

i.fas.fa-sun.nav--icon {
  color: #f2da08;
}

i.fas.fa-envelope.nav--icon {
  color: #0a2fa0;
}

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  padding-right: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    top: 1.6em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .container {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    top: 1.2em;
  }
  .nav {
    top: 70px !important;
  }
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
  -o-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(3px);
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 982px) {
  .nav {
    right: 1px !important;
    top: 84.4px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  .nav-link:hover,
  .nav-link:focus {
    background: #74d057;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 602px) {
  .nav {
    right: 1px !important;
    top: 84.4px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav {
    right: 1px !important;
    top: 84.4px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 983px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    clip-path: initial;
    -webkit-clip-path: initial;
  }
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    padding: 0.5em;
    /*margin-left: 1em;*/
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav-item {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #edbb5f;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .nav-item:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li.active-link {
    background: #edbb5f;
  }
  /*.nav a:hover,
            .nav a:focus {
                background: #edbb5f;
                padding: 7px;
            }*/
  .nav--icon {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav a {
    padding: 1.3em 2.5em 1.3em 1em;
  }
  .logo__text {
    padding: 18px 18px 18px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 480px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 361px) {
  .logo__text {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .logo__text1 {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}


/*End My Special Menu*/

.section-header-area {
  background: url(https://villablueview.cloudaccess.host/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/villa-blueview-bg02.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .section-header-area {}
}

.section-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.section-header h2 {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #565656 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.section-header h2 {
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e83ec 0%, #f6653c 100%);
}

strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.section-header h3 {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.6vw;
  color: #767676 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .section-header h2 {
    font-size: 44px;
  }
  .section-header h3 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .section-header h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  .section-header h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .section-header h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}


/*Back To Top*/

.scrollTop {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 800px;
  right: 23px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #399cf1 url(https://villablueview.cloudaccess.host/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/uparrow.png);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.scrollTop.active {
  bottom: 100px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrollTop:hover {
  background: #66b5f8 url(https://villablueview.cloudaccess.host/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/uparrow.png);
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

.showOverlay {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 983px) {
  /*to stop overlay coming into screen on desktop when clicked on menu links otherwise it brings overlay layer on top of sections then it needs to be clicked on to make it dissappear */
  .showOverlay {
    display: none;
  }
}

.hero-area {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.info-blurbs {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container-grid-masonry {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container-rooms {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green;
}

.container-reviews {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container-activities {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container-contact {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollTop" onclick="scrollToTop();"></div>
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo__text">V&#304;lla<span>Mav&#304; Manzara</span>
      <div class="logo__text1">
        <h3>KA&#350; / ANTALYA</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item amenities"><a class="nav-link" href="#amenities"><i class="fas fa-home nav--icon"></i>Amenities</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item gallery"><a class="nav-link" href="#gallery"><i class="far fa-image nav--icon"></i>Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item rooms"><a class="nav-link" href="#rooms"><i class="fas fa-bed nav--icon"></i>Rooms</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item reviews"><a class="nav-link" href="#reviews"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up nav--icon"></i>Reviews</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item activities"><a class="nav-link" href="#activities"><i class="fas fa-sun nav--icon"></i>Activities</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item contact"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact"><i class="fas fa-envelope nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
        <!--<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link availability-button" href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/18783099">Check Availability</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-area"></div>
<!--Amenities Text--->
<section id="amenities" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Amenities</strong> Villa Mavi Manzara</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Amenities Blurbs--->
<div class="info-blurbs">1</div>
<!--Gallery Text--->
<section id="gallery" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Photo</strong> Gallery</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Gallery--->
<div class="container-grid-masonry">2</div>
<!--Room Details Text--->
<section id="rooms" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Room</strong> Details</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Rooms-->
<div class="container-rooms">3</div>
<!--Review Text--->
<section id="reviews" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Reviews</strong> Villa Mavi Manzara</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Reviews-->
<div class="container-reviews">4</div>
<!--Activities Text--->
<section id="activities" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Activities</strong> Villa Mavi Manzara</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Activities-->
<div class="container-activities">5</div>
<!--Contact Text--->
<section id="contact" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Contact</strong> Us</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Contact Section-->
<div class="container-contact">6</div>
```

Comment: So basically your issue is that `active-link` is rendering on the link previous to the one that is clicked?

Comment: Yes, sorry about my English, if I take away " - headerHeight" it highlights the nav active link but then scrolled section location is off by header height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time debugging your JS but didn't find anything that stuck out to me. Then I started looking at your HTML and realized the `<div>`'s you have between each section are throwing off your `anchor` tags, making the start of the sections not display when clicking the `nav-items`. Therefore making them seem "offset".

Without additional JS, you can fix this by nesting those `<div>`'s within each respective section.

For example ~ you had this:

```html
<!--Gallery Text--->
<section id="gallery" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Photo</strong> Gallery</h2>
  </div>
</section>
<!--Gallery--->
<div class="container-grid-masonry">2</div>
<!-- div should be nested within section to not throw off anchor -->
```

Which should be this:

```html
<!--Gallery Text--->
<section id="gallery" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Photo</strong> Gallery</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Gallery--->
  <div class="container-grid-masonry">2</div>
</section>
```

See it working here:

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navLi = document.querySelectorAll(".nav li");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let current = "";
  sections.forEach((section) => {
    const sectionTop = section.offsetTop;
    const sectionHeight = section.clientHeight;
    if (pageYOffset >= sectionTop - sectionHeight / 3) {
      current = section.getAttribute("id");
    }
  });

  navLi.forEach((li) => {
    li.classList.remove("active-link");
    if (li.classList.contains(current)) {
      li.classList.add("active-link");
    }
  });
});

/*Menu Toggle*/
$(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
  $(".nav").toggleClass("nav--open", 500);
  $(".overlay").toggleClass("showOverlay");
  $(this).toggleClass("open");
});

$(".overlay").click(function() {
  $(".menu-toggle").removeClass("open");
  $(".nav").toggleClass("nav--open");
  $(".overlay").removeClass("showOverlay");
});

$(".nav a").on("click", function() {
  $(".menu-toggle").removeClass("open");
  $(".nav").toggleClass("nav--open");
  $(".overlay").removeClass("showOverlay");
});

/*Smooth Scrolling*/
// Get the height of the header for offsetting
var headerHeight = $(".header-container").height();

// Attach the click event
$('.nav-link').bind("click", function(e) {

  var target = $(this).attr("href"); //Get the target
  var scrollToPosition = $(target).offset().top - headerHeight;

  $('html').animate({
    'scrollTop': scrollToPosition
  }, 900, function(target) {
    window.location.hash = target;
  });

  e.preventDefault();
});
<!--Back To Top Script-->
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  var scroll = document.querySelector('.scrollTop');
  scroll.classList.toggle("active", window.scrollY > 500)
})

function scrollToTop() {
  window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: 'smooth',
  })
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*My Special Menu*/

html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.header-container {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7abff6 0%, #03a9f4 100%);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.container {
  /*width: 95%;
     max-width: 1000px;
    */
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1600px;
  height: 84.4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo__text {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 18px;
}

.logo__text span {
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

.logo__text1 {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 220px;
}

.logo__text1 h3 {
  font-weight: 300;
}


/*a.nav-link.availability-button {
            color: #ffffff !important;
            border-width: 0px !important;
            letter-spacing: 1.5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: 700 !important;
            background-color: #edbb5f;
            padding-top: 10px !important;
            padding-right: 18px !important;
            padding-bottom: 10px !important;
            padding-left: 18px !important;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }

        a.nav-link.availability-button:hover {
            -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
            -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
            transform: translateY(-5px);
            background-color: #edbb5f;
            padding-top: 10px !important;
            padding-right: 18px !important;
            padding-bottom: 10px !important;
            padding-left: 18px !important;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 6px;
        }*/

.nav a.active {
  color: #fff;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
  clip-path: circle(0px at top right);
  transition: -webkit-clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
  transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
  transition: clip-path ease-in-out 700ms, -webkit-clip-path ease-in-out 700ms;
}

.nav--open {
  -webkit-clip-path: circle(250% at top right);
  clip-path: circle(250% at top right);
}

.nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575766;
  border-left: 1px solid #575766;
  border-right: 1px solid #575766;
}

.nav li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
  /*.nav li:last-child {
                display: none;
            }*/
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .check-button {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.nav-link {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  padding: 2em 4em 2em 1.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  outline: none;
}


/*.nav-link:hover,
        .nav-link:focus {
            background: #74d057;
            color: #fff;
        }*/

.nav--icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 1.1em;
  text-align: right;
  /*color: #000;*/
}

i.fas.fa-home.nav--icon {
  color: #552401;
}

i.far.fa-image.nav--icon {
  color: #9a57d8;
}

i.fas.fa-bed.nav--icon {
  color: #ef991f;
}

i.far.fa-thumbs-up.nav--icon {
  color: #5912d0;
}

i.fas.fa-sun.nav--icon {
  color: #f2da08;
}

i.fas.fa-envelope.nav--icon {
  color: #0a2fa0;
}

.menu-toggle {
  padding: 1em;
  padding-right: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  right: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 3;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    top: 1.6em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  .container {
    height: 70px;
  }
  .menu-toggle {
    top: 1.2em;
  }
  .nav {
    top: 70px !important;
  }
}

.hamburger,
.hamburger::before,
.hamburger::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  height: 3px;
  width: 1.75em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
  -o-transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
  transition: all ease-in-out 500ms;
}

.hamburger::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-6px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-6px);
  transform: translateY(-6px);
}

.hamburger::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(3px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(3px);
  transform: translateY(3px);
}

.open .hamburger {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.open .hamburger::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .hamburger::after {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
  transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-90deg);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 982px) {
  .nav {
    right: 1px !important;
    top: 84.4px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
  .nav-link:hover,
  .nav-link:focus {
    background: #74d057;
    color: #fff;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 602px) {
  .nav {
    right: 1px !important;
    top: 84.4px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav {
    right: 1px !important;
    top: 84.4px;
    z-index: 15;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 983px) {
  .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav {
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    clip-path: initial;
    -webkit-clip-path: initial;
  }
  .nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
  }
  .nav a {
    padding: 0.5em;
    /*margin-left: 1em;*/
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav-item {
    position: relative;
  }
  .nav-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background: #edbb5f;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  .nav-item:hover:before {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li.active-link {
    background: #edbb5f;
  }
  /*.nav a:hover,
            .nav a:focus {
                background: #edbb5f;
                padding: 7px;
            }*/
  .nav--icon {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .nav a {
    padding: 1.3em 2.5em 1.3em 1em;
  }
  .logo__text {
    padding: 18px 18px 18px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .container {
    max-width: 480px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 361px) {
  .logo__text {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .logo__text1 {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
}


/*End My Special Menu*/

.section-header-area {
  background: url(https://villablueview.cloudaccess.host/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/villa-blueview-bg02.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .section-header-area {}
}

.section-header {
  text-align: center;
}

.section-header h2 {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #565656 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.section-header h2 {
  -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #1e83ec 0%, #f6653c 100%);
}

strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.section-header h3 {
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, Lucida, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.6vw;
  color: #767676 !important;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 980px) {
  .section-header h2 {
    font-size: 44px;
  }
  .section-header h3 {
    font-size: 26px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .section-header h2 {
    font-size: 34px;
  }
  .section-header h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 620px) {
  .section-header h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}


/*Back To Top*/

.scrollTop {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 800px;
  right: 23px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #399cf1 url(https://villablueview.cloudaccess.host/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/uparrow.png);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.scrollTop.active {
  bottom: 100px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.scrollTop:hover {
  background: #66b5f8 url(https://villablueview.cloudaccess.host/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/uparrow.png);
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 2;
}

.showOverlay {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 983px) {
  /*to stop overlay coming into screen on desktop when clicked on menu links otherwise it brings overlay layer on top of sections then it needs to be clicked on to make it dissappear */
  .showOverlay {
    display: none;
  }
}

.hero-area {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.info-blurbs {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container-grid-masonry {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.container-rooms {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: green;
}

.container-reviews {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.container-activities {
  height: 700px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.container-contact {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scrollTop" onclick="scrollToTop();"></div>
<div class="header-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo__text">V&#304;lla<span>Mav&#304; Manzara</span>
      <div class="logo__text1">
        <h3>KA&#350; / ANTALYA</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <nav class="nav">
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item amenities"><a class="nav-link" href="#amenities"><i class="fas fa-home nav--icon"></i>Amenities</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item gallery"><a class="nav-link" href="#gallery"><i class="far fa-image nav--icon"></i>Gallery</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item rooms"><a class="nav-link" href="#rooms"><i class="fas fa-bed nav--icon"></i>Rooms</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item reviews"><a class="nav-link" href="#reviews"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up nav--icon"></i>Reviews</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item activities"><a class="nav-link" href="#activities"><i class="fas fa-sun nav--icon"></i>Activities</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item contact"><a class="nav-link" href="#contact"><i class="fas fa-envelope nav--icon"></i>Contact</a></li>
        <!--<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link availability-button" href="https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/18783099">Check Availability</a></li>-->
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="menu-toggle">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hero-area"></div>
<!--Amenities Text--->
<section id="amenities" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Amenities</strong> Villa Mavi Manzara</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Amenities Blurbs--->
  <div class="info-blurbs">1</div>
</section>

<!--Gallery Text--->
<section id="gallery" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Photo</strong> Gallery</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Gallery--->
  <div class="container-grid-masonry">2</div>
</section>

<!--Room Details Text--->
<section id="rooms" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Room</strong> Details</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Rooms-->
  <div class="container-rooms">3</div>
</section>

<!--Review Text--->
<section id="reviews" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Reviews</strong> Villa Mavi Manzara</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Reviews-->
  <div class="container-reviews">4</div>
</section>

<!--Activities Text--->
<section id="activities" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Activities</strong> Villa Mavi Manzara</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Activities-->
  <div class="container-activities">5</div>
</section>

<!--Contact Text--->
<section id="contact" class="section-header-area">
  <div class="section-header">
    <h2><strong>Contact</strong> Us</h2>
  </div>
  <!--Contact Section-->
  <div class="container-contact">6</div>
</section>
```

Edit ~ [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/kameronmayers/pen/LYOOvby) does not make the `.nav-items` background colors jump around when going from top to bottom. Also, solves the Issues of "Amenities" being highlighted when at the top of the page.

Comment: how about my second problem:

Comment: @Seventhplanet no problem! Are you referring to the `background-color` on `nav-items` skipping through each other when you go from *amenities* to *contact* for example?

Comment: During scrolling, highlighting backgroung color passes by each link and creates unpleasant effects for example when you are in the Amenities section and click on Contact to reach to contact section every nav links from Amenities to Contack is highlighted one by one instead of just Contact gets highlighted when scroll happens

Comment: @Seventhplanet give me a few moments and I will take a look.

Comment: I know html and css but I have a very little knowledge of JS so i usually search and copy and paste codes to suit my design. I have found a cleaner code to implement it on my style, that  nav-items skipping through each other is not the case anymore but i have another problem shows up for me which is when i click on scroll to top button AMENITIES link is highlighted, it shouldn't happen because it is not amenities section, there is hero section on top of it without a link. can i share it with you at a codepen link?

Comment: @Seventhplanet yes ~ send me the Codepen link.

Comment: Thanks man, I have two codes for active link on js, //Highlight active link on scroll and //Highlight active link on click. if you take away on scroll code and work only with on click you will see that clicking on scroll to top button takes away amenities highlight on the top, so in this example I would like to have same effect using only on scroll code as I will not need on click code. here is the link, https://codepen.io/OralYildiz/pen/YzExmed

Comment: Here is a link that includes the **jQuery scroll code:** https://codepen.io/kameronmayers/pen/LYOOvby ~ what you're experiencing is standard behavior for `anchor` tags. What I would do is add another `li` under `nav-list` and call it "Hero" with the `href="hero-area"`. I added an `id` next to the `.hero-area` class for this to work. Then you can just use this CSS: `.nav-list li:nth-child(1) { display: none;}` which I added at the bottom of your CSS. This should have the functionality you want.

Comment: @Seventhplanet sorry the response took so long ~ been a busy day.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind attention, that works very well.